# Is there any way to pop up a balloon on event? (chrome extension)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to make extension to pop up when event occurs?
Let's say it should listening to an online webpage and when it change (the page) it will pop up a balloon.
I would love to hear any ideas. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Desktop Notifications....
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html

Answer (score 2):

No. They only way a browserAction popup will open is if a user clicks on the button.

> If a browser action has a popup, the popup appears when the user clicks the icon.

https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#popups